# How to use lambdas and functions as custom deleters for unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, unique-ptr

I'm testing custom deleters for `unique_ptr`.
Strangely, only deleters that are function objects work fine.
If I replace them with functions or lambdas, program doesn't compile.
What am I doing wrong?

Here is my complete test program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;


class Vehicle {
public:
    Vehicle(){ cout<<"Vehicle constructor..."<<endl;}
    virtual ~Vehicle(){cout<<"~Vehicle destructor..."<<endl;}
    virtual void go()=0;
};

class Car:public Vehicle {
    public:
    void go() override {
        cout<<"Going by car..."<<endl;
    }
};

class Bicycle:public Vehicle {
    public:
    void go() override {
        cout<<"Going by bicycle..."<<endl;
    }
};

// Custom deleters
auto CustomLambdaDeleter = [](Vehicle* v){
    cout<<"Custom lambda deleter called..."<<endl;
    delete v;
};

void CustomFunctionDeleter(Vehicle* v){
    cout<<"Custom function deleter called..."<<endl;
    delete v;
}

struct CustomFunctorDeleter
{
    void operator()(Vehicle* v ) const {
        cout<<"Custom functor deleter called..."<<endl;
        delete v;
    }
};


// Doesn't compile
//using VehiclePtr = unique_ptr<Vehicle, decltype(CustomLambdaDeleter)>;
// Doesn't compile
//using VehiclePtr = unique_ptr<Vehicle, decltype(&CustomFunctionDeleter)>;
// Works ok
using VehiclePtr = unique_ptr<Vehicle, CustomFunctorDeleter>;


class VehicleFactory {
public:
    static VehiclePtr createVehicle(string type){
        VehiclePtr vptr;
        if("bicycle"==type) {
            vptr.reset(new Bicycle());
            // This also works
            // vptr= (VehiclePtr) new Bicycle();
            return vptr;
        }
        else if("car"==type) {

           vptr.reset( new Car());
           return vptr;
        }

        return nullptr;
    }
};


void vehicleFactoryTest(){
    cout<<"* Starting vehicleFactoryTest()..."<<endl;
    auto firstVehicle = VehicleFactory::createVehicle("bicycle");
    firstVehicle->go();
    auto newCar = VehicleFactory::createVehicle("car");
    newCar->go();
}

int main(int, char **)
{

    vehicleFactoryTest();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To help people answer your question, you'll need to be more specific about the error.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the exact errors you get from your [mcve] (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: I get the following  error: use of deleted function '<lambda(Vehicle*)>::<lambda>()'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem isn't with either of

```
using VehiclePtr = unique_ptr<Vehicle, decltype(CustomLambdaDeleter)>;
```

or

```
using VehiclePtr = unique_ptr<Vehicle, CustomFunctorDeleter>;
```

Those two compile by themselves. The problem lies with the following line within `createVehicle`

```
VehiclePtr vptr;
```

Here, you're default constructing a `unique_ptr`, which will not compile in case of the lambda deleter because lambdas are not default constructible. So you need

```
VehiclePtr vptr{nullptr, CustomLambdaDeleter};
```

In the case where you're using a function pointer, you're attempting to default construct the `unique_ptr` with a `nullptr` deleter, which is not allowed. The fix is similar, you need to pass a pointer to the function in that case.

```
VehiclePtr vptr{nullptr, CustomFunctionDeleter};
```

You're also making a similar error in the final return statement in `createVehicle`. Change that line to

```
return vptr;
```

Comment: @Fedorov7890 Updated, there was another error in your return statement. If you still have problems, please use an online compiler and paste a link to the example that won't compile.

Comment: Thanks, the change from 'return nullptr' to 'return vptr' fixed the problem.